# how to use regex to remove duplicate lines that adds words each line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to remove the repeating lines from a given input. And the input is a total mess. For example below is an example input.

```
HISTORY
HISTORY TV"
HISTORY TV" THIS
HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND
HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND ON
HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3.
WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3.
WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3. "THE
WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3. "THE MARCH
WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3. "THE MARCH ON
WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3. "THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON"
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS AND
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS AND FREEDOM
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS AND FREEDOM WAS
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS AND FREEDOM WAS 49
FOR JOBS AND FREEDOM WAS 49 YEARS
FOR JOBS AND FREEDOM WAS 49 YEARS AGO.
YEARS AGO. ON
YEARS AGO. ON AUGUST
YEARS AGO. ON AUGUST 28th,
YEARS AGO. ON AUGUST 28th, 1963.
ON AUGUST 28th, 1963. THE
ON AUGUST 28th, 1963. THE MARCH
ON AUGUST 28th, 1963. THE MARCH WAS
ON AUGUST 28th, 1963. THE MARCH WAS ORKGANIZED
ON AUGUST 28th, 1963. THE MARCH WAS ORKGANIZED TO
ON AUGUST 28th, 1963. THE MARCH WAS ORKGANIZED TO PUSH
THE MARCH WAS ORKGANIZED TO PUSH FOR
THE MARCH WAS ORKGANIZED TO PUSH FOR COMPREHENSIVE
THE MARCH WAS ORKGANIZED TO PUSH FOR COMPREHENSIVE CIVIL
THE MARCH WAS ORKGANIZED TO PUSH FOR COMPREHENSIVE CIVIL RIGHTS
FOR COMPREHENSIVE CIVIL RIGHTS INCLUDING
FOR COMPREHENSIVE CIVIL RIGHTS INCLUDING PUBLIC
FOR COMPREHENSIVE CIVIL RIGHTS INCLUDING PUBLIC SCHOOL
INCLUDING PUBLIC SCHOOL DESEGREGATION,
INCLUDING PUBLIC SCHOOL DESEGREGATION, VOTING
INCLUDING PUBLIC SCHOOL DESEGREGATION, VOTING RIGHTS
DESEGREGATION, VOTING RIGHTS PROTECTION
```

Here is a desired output

```
HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3.
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS AND FREEDOM WAS 49
ON AUGUST 28th, 1963. THE MARCH WAS ORKGANIZED TO PUSH
FOR COMPREHENSIVE CIVIL RIGHTS INCLUDING PUBLIC SCHOOL
DESEGREGATION, VOTING RIGHTS PROTECTION
```

which that it's human readable and has just the non repeating sentences.

below is a code I have right now

```
import os
import re

directory = './reprocess'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    
    print("Processing... {}".format(filename))

    with open("./reprocess/"+filename, "r") as inputFile:
        data = inputFile.read().splitlines()

    new_data = ""
    
    for line in data:
        new_data = new_data + line + "\n"

    cleaned = re.sub(r"(\b[\w']+(?:[\s.]+[\w']+)*)(?=[\s.]+\1)[\s.]+", '\n', new_data)
    cleaned = re.sub(r"\A\n+|(?<=[^.] )\n+|\n+(?=\n)|\n+\Z", '', cleaned)
    
    with open("./reprocess_out/"+filename, "w") as outFile:
        outFile.write(cleaned)
```

and have a horrible output

```
HISTORY TV"
HISTORY TV" THIS
HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND
HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND ON
HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3.
WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3.
WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3. "THE
WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3. "THE MARCH
WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3. "THE MARCH ON
WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3. "THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON"
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS AND
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS AND FREEDOM
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS AND FREEDOM WAS
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS AND FREEDOM WAS 49 YEARS AGO. ON AUGUST 28th,
YEARS AGO. ON AUGUST 28th, 1963.
ON AUGUST 28th, 1963. THE
ON AUGUST 28th, 1963. THE MARCH
ON AUGUST 28th, 1963. THE MARCH WAS
```

Please let me know how I can solve this problem. This sure is a complex one and This regex is not really doing the job I wanted it to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "repeated lines"?   Every line in your file appears to be unique.

Comment: I mean that ```HISTORY TV" HISTORY TV" THIS``` etc where there's repetition. each line adds just one word after the last one. Worst of all There are lines such as ```HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3.``` and then there's a new line like ```WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3. "THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON"```

Comment: Just saying "there's repetition" doesn't really help.  What is the *logic* to determine if a line belongs in the result?

Comment: Why doesn't anything starting with `WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3.` belong in the result?

Comment: @ScottHunter well the logic is to get every single sentence in the input file, without having any kind of repetition. ```HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3``` because it's a full sentence in the input surrounded by many similar sentences.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit (not all lines have new words):**

In this case I would do the following:

```py
last_words = [data[0]]
for line in data:
    last_word = line.split()[-1] # could be changed to a regex
    if last_words[-1] != last_word:
        last_words.append(last_word)

cleaned = " ".join(last_words)
```

In this case `data` a the list of lines.

---

**Previous answer:**

According to your comment: "each line adds just one word after the last one".

In this case you can simply get the last words from all lines:

```
res = re.findall("(\S*)\n", data)
print(" ".join(res))
```

where `data` is the input as one string, not split by lines.

This will give you the desired output, only in one line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes that is the logic. However, if you analyze the input we have cases like ```HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3.``` followed by ```WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3.``` which is the exact same sentence. From all that lines, I need to extract ```HISTORY TV" THIS WEEKEND ON C-SPAN3.
"THE MARCH ON WASHINGTON" FOR JOBS AND FREEDOM WAS 49``` and so on. Your code doesn't produce the desired output I outlined.

Comment: You're right I've missed that. I've updated my answer, hope it does what you wanted now.